# index.php not working properly?

Tags: php, .htaccess

So I need to put together simple website using php- header and footer will be the same and the middle section changes. I need to be able to click on the link in header and change the section (hem or nyheter, hem is the default).
What may be the reasons the following code does not work once I click on link in the header? It loads correctly the first time, but once I click on the link, the header and footer does not load, only the section part opens in a browser.
I have htaccess file and header, footer and sections files are on the same level.

Thanks in advance!

```
<?php

$sections = array("hem", "nyheter");
$sectionTitles = array("HEM", "NYHETER");

$section = "hem";

$content = explode("/", $_SERVER['REQUEST_URI']);

if (!empty($content[2]) && (in_array($content[2], $sections))) { $section = $content[2];}

include ("header.php");
include ("$section.php");
include ("footer.php");

?>
```

Header code:

```
<body>
    <a href="hem">hem</a> | <a href="nyheter">nyheter</a>
```

.htaccess:

```
 RewriteEngine On
 RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !\.(php|css|js|gif|png|jpe?g|pdf|eot|svg|ttf|woff|ico)$
 RewriteRule (.*)$ index.php [L]
```

Comment: have you tried removing codes from include ("$section.php");

Comment: I remember you posting this earlier and deleted that other question. Check for errors if there happens to be any with error reporting.

Comment: direct include is not a good idea, because it`s posible to include any file from your server

Comment: you do know that `hem` and `HEM` etc. are two different animals here. If you're running this off a \*NIX system and you're trying to include `hem.php` as opposed to `HEM.php` then that's a problem. Are you not paying attention to comments in here? I specifically said to check for errors via error reporting but you seem to only be responding to answers posted. `<a href="hem">hem</a>` suggests a folder called `hem` with an `index.php` file in it and the same for the other one. Again; check for errors and/or look at your logs and make sure you're running this off a webserver `http://localhost`.

Comment: @Fred-ii- HEM is section title, that I will be outputting (sectionTitles[0], for example). hem is hem.php minus php, that is being taken care of in .htaccess file.
But thank you for your input :)

Comment: 1. Your links should be `/hem` 2. I'm pretty sure that `$content[2]` does not contain what you expected (dump it with `echo` or `var_dump` if you have xdebug installed) 3. Before testing if it's empty, test if it's set with `isset($content[2])`

Comment: if @Bobot said is correct, then error reporting http://php.net/manual/en/function.error-reporting.php would have signaled a non-existant file/folder and in logs.

Comment: You can activate it by using `ini_set('display_errors', true); error_reporting(E_ALL);` just after your opening PHP tag. Or through your PHP config in `php.ini`

Comment: It is set, because on page load I get header+hem+footer. (also, isset($content[2]) gives out section). The problem is with the link.. This shouldn't abe a rocket science, but I guess I can't really explain my problem.

Comment: Checking for `isset()` is redundant. `empty()` already takes care of that.

Answer (score 0):

I tried using the site url that i have added please try with is, it worked for me and change your code according to you

```
    <?php

$sections = array("hem", "nyheter");
$sectionTitles = array("HEM", "NYHETER");

$section = "hem";

$sitefolder = "/krist";
$site_url   = "http://".$_SERVER["HTTP_HOST"].$sitefolder.'/index.php';

$content = explode("/", $_SERVER['REQUEST_URI']);

if (!empty($content[2]) && (in_array($content[2], $sections))) { $section = $content[2];}

include ("header.php");
include ($section.".php");
include ("footer.php");

?>
```

Header code:

```
<body>
<a href="<?php echo $site_url.'/hem'?>">hem</a> | <a href="nyheter">nyheter</a>
```

Comment: you've a missing line closure, on line 1 btw.

Comment: no problemo ;-) I sure hope that solves it for them. Let's see what they have to say about it.

Comment: Thanks for your input! But this seems to not be a problem.. The browser outputs whole page (header + section(hem, as it is default) + footer on load. But once I click on link in teh header, it outputs only section part, without header and footer. I can't figure out what is missing..

Comment: this is not a problem while `"$section.php"` is exactly the same this than `$section.'.php'`, see difference between simple & double quotes in PHP string iterpretation ;)

Comment: I get this as a url after clicking on link: http://localhost/krist/index.php/nyheter

But thanks anyway.

Comment: i have added "krist" as my folder name you need to add your folder in place of "krist"

Comment: I understand, @rahul, link still is strange. Thanks anyway.